# What is the purpose of * in Fortran input/output

Tags: fortran

I am learning Fortran because well, yeah, thought I'd learn it. However, I've found utterly no information on what the purpose of * is in print, read, etc:

```
program main

    print *, "Hello, world!"

end program main
```

What is the purpose of this `*`? I've done some research however I don't think I understand it properly, I don't want to carry on learning until I actually know the point of `*`.

From what I've managed to find I think that it's some sort of format specifier, however, I don't understand what that means and I have no idea if I'm even correct. All the tutorials I've found just tell me what to write to print to the console but not what `*` actually means.

Comment: the formal term is "list directed" formatting in case you want to google for details

Comment: Even in I/O there are other `*`s, but hopefully you find this a more informative title.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are correct in that it is a format specifier.

There's a page on Wikibooks to do with [IO](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Fortran/io) and that states:

> The second * specifies the format the user wants the number read with

when talking about the `read` statement. This applies to the `write` and `print` statements too.

> For fixed point reals: Fw.d; w is the total number of spaces alloted for the number, and d is the number of decimal places.

And the example they give is

```
REAL :: A
READ(*,'(F5.2)') A
```

which reads a real number with 2 digits before and after the decimal point. So if you were printing a real number you'd use:

```
PRINT '(F5.2)', A
```

to get the rounded output.

In your example you're just printing text so there's no special formatting to do. Also if you leave the format specifier as `*` it will apply the default formatting to reals etc.

Answer (score 4):

The `print` statement does formatted output to a special place (which we assume is the screen).  There are three available ways to specify the format used in this output.  One of these, as in the question, is using `*`.

The `*` format specifier means that the formatted output will be so-called *list-directed* output.  Conversely, for a `read` statement, it will be list-directed input.  Now that the term has been introduced you will be able to find many other questions here: list-directed input/output has many potentially surprising consequences.

Generally, a format specification item says how to format an item in the input/output list.  If we are writing out a real number we'd use a format item which may, say, state the precision of the output or whether it uses scientific notation.

As in the question, when writing out a character variable we may want to specify the width of the output field (so that there is blank padding, or partial output) or not.  We could have

```
print '(A20)', "Hello, world!"
print '(A5)', "Hello, world!"
print '(A)', "Hello, world!"
```

which offers a selection of effects.  [Using a literal character constant like `'(A)'` is one of the other ways of giving the format.]

But we couldn't have

```
print '(F12.5)', "Hello, world!"   ! A numeric format for a character variable
```

as our format doesn't make sense with the output item.

List-directed output is different from the above cases.  Instead, (quote here and later from the Fortran 2008 draft standard) this

> allows data editing according to the type of the list item instead of by a format specification. It also allows data to be free-field, that is, separated by commas (or semicolons) or blanks.

The main effect, and why list-directed is such a convenience, is that no effort is required on the part of the programmer to craft a suitable format for the things to be sent out.

When an output list is processed under list-directed output and a real value appears it is as though the programmer gave a suitable format for that value.  And the same for other types.

But the crucial thing here is "a suitable format".  The end user doesn't get to say `A5` or `F12.5`.  Instead of that latter the compiler gets to choose "reasonable processor-dependent values" for widths, precisions and so on.  [Leading to questions like "why so much white space?".]  The constraints on the output are given in, for example, Fortran 2008 10.10.4.

So, in summary `*` is saying, print out the following things in a *reasonable* way.  I won't complain how you choose to do this, even if you give me output like

```
 5*0
      1     2
```

rather than

```
 0 0 0 0 0 1 2
```

and I certainly won't complain about having a leading space like

```
 Hello, world!
```

rather than

```
Hello, world!
```

For, yes, with list-directed you will (except in cases beyond this answer) get an initial blank on the output:

> Except for new records created by [a special case] or by continuation of delimited character sequences, each output record begins with a blank character.