# How to eliminate the blank space in the begining of the text field in Fortran?

Tags: fortran, fortran90, gfortran

I want to write some data in a text file using a Fortran code. I am able to do that. But, I am getting blank space in the beginning of the every line which is inappropriate for my application. I have given the code and the output of the code below:

```
PROGRAM MAIN
IMPLICIT NONE
REAL        ::   PHI

PHI = 0.3000;

OPEN(UNIT=222,FILE='settings.txt',STATUS='NEW',ACTION='READWRITE')

WRITE(222,*) "What is the number?"
WRITE(222,*) PHI

END PROGRAM
```

The output of the code is

```
  What is the number?
  0.3000
```

My desired output would be without the blank space at the beginnning,

```
what is the number?
0.3000
```

So, how do I eliminate the blank space at the beginning of the text field?

Comment: You can find detail in answers to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/34436125).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The blank space is always in list-directed output (the * format). You must use an explicit format to start in column 1.

```
WRITE(222,'(g0)') "What is the number?"
WRITE(222,'(g0)') PHI
```

I used the most general descriptor g0 from Fortran 2008 because you are not interested in the detailed control.

Comment: for the first WRITE statement, the format should be '(a)'

Comment: @FrancoisJacq It doesn't have to be. G0 is a general edit descriptor. G0 is equivalent to A for character output items.

Comment: If one of them should be changed, it would be the second one to `f6.4` or `f0.4` or similar.

Comment: @VladimirF OK I learn something today about Fortran ! Thanks !