# Convert unformatted Fortran output to formatted

Tags: fortran

I'm having a problem in reversing the following lines of Fortran code

```
OPEN (UNIT=3,STATUS='NEW',FORM='UNFORMATTED',FILE='OUT3')

NK = 20
WRITE (3)  NTOT, MODEL, NRUN, NK
WRITE (3)  (AS(K),K=1,NK), (BODYS(J),J=1,NTOT),
&          ((XS(K,J),K=1,3),J=1,NTOT), ((VS(K,J),K=1,3),J=1,NTOT),
&          (NAME(J),J=1,NTOT)
```

After writing them in UNFORMATTED form, I'd like to read them and translate them into a FORMATTED form. Or maybe change the following lines to write directly the variables in FORMATTED form (however it seems not to work by writing `FORM='FORMATTED'`).

Comment: If you want to use formatted output then you will need to specify a format.  One way would be to use [list-directed output](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34436125/3157076).

Comment: Please provide more details. "does not work" isn't descriptive enough to evaluate or effectively answer the question.

Comment: Could you show the reading code and how you are writing them as formatted