# Using fortran to convert between unformatted binary data and .txt format

Tags: fortran

I'm currently working with a code/program (written in Fortran) where I need to provide some data in binary format. I am completely new to Fortran and also storing data in binary format. So currently, I'm trying to understand how I can convert the binary information to a readable .txt file, so I can ensure I store it the correct way.

Take for example the following code:

---

```
program data_to_bin
integer :: i
real(kind=8) :: x
integer(kind=1) :: spherical, linear, even
spherical = 1
linear = 0
even = 0
open(1,file="5data",form="unformatted")
write(1) spherical,linear,even
do i = 1, 5
    read(*,*) x
    write(1) x
    write(*,*) i, x
end do
close(1)
end program data_to_bin
```

If I run ./a.out <data.txt (where data.txt consist of a column with 5 numbers), then I create the file "5data".

But how do I read this file again?
I tried writing the following code:

```
program bin_to_data
integer :: i
character :: x
open(1,file="5data.txt",form="formatted")
do i = 1, 8
    read(*,*) x
    write(1) x
    write(*,*) i, x
end do
close(1)
end program bin_to_data
```

If I enter ./a.out <5data in the terminal I get the error message "At line 7 of file bin_to_data.f90 (unit = 1, file = '5data.txt')
Fortran runtime error: Missing format for FORMATTED data transfer".

Comment: If you want to do formatted output then you need to specify a format, much as you have with `write(*,*) i, x` each time.  What do you want the output to look like?

Comment: @francescalus Maybe I don't quite understand how binary data is saved. But I assumed it conserved the same array structure and just converted numbers, etc to binary format. So my goal is to convert the binary file to an output with the same array structure as the binary file, but readable, so I can find possible errors in the way I store the data.

Comment: Does that make sense? or is it complete nonsense? :D 
Would it be enough to replace write(1,*) x? If I do that, it just tells me that it's at the end of the file. So does binary file only consist of one line?

Comment: Output (formatted and unformatted) does not preserve structure of the object being written. It works only on values. If you say "write out this array with three columns" you get three columns, whatever the shape of the array. You will need to understand _records_ in each case. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34436125/3157076) you can read about `write(1,*) x`.